# unix script, running a command on multiple files

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have no previous experience with writing a unix script but what I want seems like a simple task.. I want to run this command for all the pdf files in a folder

```
pdf2txt.py -o naacl06-shinyama.html samples/naacl06-shinyama.pdf
```

if there is a file called anypdf.pdf the command would look like:

```
pdf2txt.py -o anypdf.html samples/anypdf.pdf
```

so if my folder includes 3 pdf files like, abc.pdf aaa.pdf bbb.pdf I want to end up with abc.html aaa.html and bbb.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for pdf in samples/*.pdf; do
    html=$(basename "$pdf" .pdf).html
    pdf2txt.py -o "$html" "$pdf"
done
```

If you don't have `basename` then try this alternative, which uses bash's `##` and `%` constructs to do replacements inline.

```
#!/bin/bash

for pdf in samples/*.pdf; do
    html=${pdf##*/};
    html=${html%.pdf}.html
    pdf2txt.py -o "$html" "$pdf"
done
```

Comment: thanks but I getting a (i believe) a python error like TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outdir'

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven Check that it's running `pdf2txt.py` with the correct arguments. That error's coming from Python, not from the shell.